# Unwrapping nil optional when updating google map camera in didselectrowatindexpath

Tags: swift, option-type, google-maps-sdk-ios, didselectrowatindexpath

I'm using the `google-maps-sdk` and I have a `UITableView` and a `GMSMapView` in the same `viewcontroller`. I put `autocomplete search` results in the `tableview`, and I want to move the map to the location represented by the cell the user selects. I am trying to update the map in the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method but I keep getting the "unwrapped nil optional error." This is pretty confusing because I literally assign the optional to a value one line above where I try to unwrap it.

I get the error when I assign self.mapview to camera. Any help/ideas would be much appreciated. Thanks!

`ViewDidLoad` method

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.tableView.dataSource = self
        self.tableView.delegate = self

        self.resultSearchController = ({
            let controller = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
            controller.searchResultsUpdater = self
            controller.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
            controller.searchBar.sizeToFit()
            controller.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
            self.navigationItem.titleView = controller.searchBar
            //self.tableView.tableHeaderView = controller.searchBar
            return controller
        })()

        placesClient = GMSPlacesClient()

        var camera: GMSCameraPosition = GMSCameraPosition.cameraWithLatitude(-33.86,
            longitude: 151.20, zoom: 6)
        self.mapSubView.camera = camera
        self.mapSubView = GMSMapView.mapWithFrame(CGRectZero, camera: camera)
        self.mapSubView.myLocationEnabled = true



        var marker = GMSMarker()
        marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(-33.86, 151.20)
        marker.title = "Sydney"
        marker.snippet = "Australia"
        marker.map = mapSubView


    }
```

`didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method

```
  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
    view.sendSubviewToBack(self.tableView)
    var result = searchResults[indexPath.row]
    var camera = GMSCameraPosition.cameraWithLatitude(42.37, longitude: -71.109734, zoom: 16)
    self.mapSubView.camera = camera
    self.mapSubView = GMSMapView.mapWithFrame(self.mapSubView.bounds, camera: self.mapSubView.camera)

}
```

Comment: It looks like mapSubView is nil and you got the error when trying to access its camera property. Is mapSubView your mapView ?

Comment: Yes mapSubView is my mapView. It shouldn't be nil because I initialize in viewDidLoad. Thanks!

Comment: I checked my code and I think your right about the mapview being nil. Do you know why though? I already assigned it to something in viewDidLoad. Is there way I could initialize it?

Comment: No I dont know why until you post your viewDidLoad code

Comment: just did. thanks for your help!

Comment: Checkout my answer now

Answer (score 0):

Now I clearly know where your problem is :

```
if let mapSubView2 = self.mapSubView {
 mapSubView2.camera = camera
 self.mapSubView = mapView
}
```

This condition is NEVER met so thats why your mapSubView is nil. Why? I think you intention was to write something like

```
if let mapSubView2 = mapView {
 mapSubView2.camera = camera
 self.mapSubView = mapSubView2
}
```

But you can skip all these check and directly assign mapSubView as follow

```
self.mapSubView = GMSMapView.mapWithFrame(CGRectZero, camera: camera)
self.mapSubView.myLocationEnabled = true
```

Comment: I didn't originally have that. I added that to see if the mapView was actually nil like you said. And it does get initialized because the line above it is: var mapView = GMSMapView.mapWithFrame(CGRectZero, camera: camera). Sorry for posting confusing code. I can change it back bit it will still have say its nil when I try to unwrap it in didselectrowatindexpath.